# Gatsby-source-apiserver 2.1.0 entitiesArray

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Whenever I use the

```
entitiesArray: [
        {
          url: `http://yourapi.com/api/v1/posts`,
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          name: `posts`,
          // optional paging
          calculateNextPage: (curUrl, response, context) => {
            let page = 2
            if (context.page) {
              page = context.page + 1
            }
            context.page = page
            const url = `http://yourapi.com/api/v1/posts?page=${page}`
            const hasNext = response.data.length >= 100
            return { url, hasNext }
          }   
        }
      ]
```

it saves my data into an array of objects, but the way my program is setup is to read from just one object. Is there any I can fix this?

Comment: Where's the "program"?

Comment: @FerranBuireu what do you mean

Comment: Can you clarify this part? "but the way my program is setup is to read from just one object. Is there any I can fix this?"